# Output Generation Problem (P.s The Code Runs)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to plot a diagonal from a range of a single row. When I first ran the code, it generated the values but when i tried again, the code runs but no output is generated. Any suggestions?

```
Sub diagonal()

    Dim i As Integer, rng As Range, col As Integer, ro As Integer
    Set rng = Range("C32:L32").Rows(32).CurrentRegion
    Dim cell As Range
    col = 25
    ro = 37
    For Each cell In rng
        col = col - 1
        ro = ro + 1
        cell.Value = cell(ro, col)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `Debug.Print rng.Address` just after the `Set rng` line. Compare the results from the first run with subsequent runs.

Comment: hi @Sam , i tried your debug line, but its still not generating the result

Comment: That was not the expected result. What is the output from the debug statement?

Comment: nothing. nothing is displayed anywhere.

Comment: but when i check the locals window, "cell" shows a value of "nothing" in it. Could it be of some concern?

Comment: Just to make sure - is the output pane visible? Press Ctrl+G if not

Comment: You should add an explicit reference to the worksheet to which the range belongs. For example `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of ws").Range(......)`

Comment: nothing is working. output pane is also not visible and neither is the explicit reference working